# SQL Parsing in C#?

Tags: c#

in my application , i have a textbox where user can paste Sql (mainly from MS-ACCESS) , i need to parse this SQL and get the table names , joins , Columns etc.

is there a easy in c# rather than using string manupulation to do this activity?

i can think of implementing a BST aslo but don't have any clue where to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Irony for C#](http://irony.codeplex.com/) has an LALR parser with several grammars already created, including one for SQL (as you can see from the screenshot on the home page).  It's a very easy to use parser using operator overloads to define the grammars in a way reminiscent to BNF.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) using [SQL Server 2000 grammar](http://antlr.org/grammar/1062280680642/MS_SQL_SELECT.html) as a template.

Comment: can't use custom parsers as this is very project specific?

Answer (score 1):

I've done some work using the gold parser to be able to parse and programatically explore SQL statements. In my case it is SQL 89 which would not include a fair amount of access syntax but may be someone you could build on.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/QueryAnything.aspx

It's still somewhat experimental but the underlying parsing is pretty flexible.

Comment: can't use custom parsers as this is very project specific?

Answer (score 1):

I have had some success using this: https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/SQLGeneration
It's free to use, is open source, worth checking out.